# How to call the second function after the first function is executed completely?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm new to JavaScript. I have 2 javascript functions below. Basically, I want the the first function is run until the user fills out the textbox. Otherwise the textbox will get focused forever. After the first function is completely executed, the second function will be kicked off to display an alert saying everything is satisfied,  the system is sending email to supervisor. Is it possible that I just put the entire second function into the first function so that the second function will be executed after the first function is completely done? Can someone give me any advices? I appreciate your help and thanks a lot.

```
function DisableUpdateBtn(txtAnimal)
{
If(txtAnimal.text == "")
   {
   Alert("Animal is required!");
   txtAnimal.focus();
   return false;
   }
     Return true;
}

function AllowToUpdate(ckbApprove,txtUserApproval)
{
    If(ckbApprove.checked && txtUserApproval.text != "")
    {
       Alert("Conditions are met! Sending Approval to Supervisor!");
       Return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [callback](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) function, for example:

```
function runMeFirst(callback)
{
  /** Some code here. **/

  if (typeof callback == 'function')
    callback();
}

function anotherFunc()
{
  alert('Another Func!');
}
```

**Usage**

```
runMeFirst(anotherFunc);

runMeFirst(function () {
    /** Your code here. **/
});
```